# Continuous integration with GitHub

Tags: asp.net-mvc, git, github, msbuild, github-api

Currently we are using TFS as our source control. We have configured Continuous Integration with TFS and its working fine. But now we have decided to move our project to GitHub.

Its ASP.NET MVC project and we already have Msbuild's proj file that builds the project and creates output.
Now ***somehow*** we need to run the proj file automatically when someone push the code to remote repository. I am not worrying about deploying the code.

I see GitHub has 2 options:

- Webhooks: I guess we have to create our own service that accepts "POST" request and then host the service on our own build server. This service will be responsible for the PULLing latest code into local repository on build server and executing proj file.
- There are few integration tools available on GitHub, but im not sure which one works with MSBUILD. Any recommendation on integration tool, specifically for ASP.NET MVC project? https://github.com/integrations/feature/build

Any recommendation on these 2 approaches?

Comment: Are you building your code on TFS now?

Answer (score 2):

## TFS Build

If you're using [TFS Build 2015](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/vs/alm/Build/feature-overview) it's just a matter of [couple of clicks](http://blog.ehn.nu/2015/06/12/building-github-repositories-in-tfs-build-vnext/):

1. Create a GitHub account for your build server
2. Generate Personal access token (and define permissions) for this account
3. Create new build definition (use GitHub option)

If you're not going to use TFS Build but you want to choose another build server, you have plenty of options on the market.

## Cloud solution

For example you can choose [AppVeyor](http://www.appveyor.com/docs). This is a cloud CI service which has out of the box integration with GitHub and can easily build .NET solutions. It uses WebHooks to trigger the build process.

## In-house build server

Let's say that you want to have your own CI server. As a solution for .NET I can recommend [TeamCity](https://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/), but you can also use Jenkins. Both has integration with GitHub and both can build .NET code.

I'm more familiar with TC, so I'll explain how to configure it.

TeamCity Pro [is free for](https://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/buy/) small teams.

You can find a step by step example [here](http://www.mehdi-khalili.com/continuous-integration-delivery-github-teamcity). It's a little bit outdated (the article is written in 2013), but still it's a decent tutorial.

1. You need an account for the build server (same as for TFS Build).
2. Configure VCS root to use your GitHub repository.
3. Set up branch specification. Most often `+:refs/heads/*` is ok.
4. Define build steps. Give it a path to `.sln` file.
5. Define other steps if needed (unit tests, publish package, notifications)
6. Set up build triggers (TC can poll GitHub for changes, or it can listen to WebHook). First option is good when TC is behind the firewall.

The steps for [Jenkins](http://justinramel.com/2013/01/15/5-minute-setup/) will be [slightly different](http://fourkitchens.com/blog/article/trigger-jenkins-builds-pushing-github), but it's not too complicated as well.

## WebHook vs Poll

The minimum polling interval for TC is one minute. If you're agree to wait, or if your TC instance is not open to public (installed behind the firewall) use this option to trigger the build.

If you want almost instant build and your build server has public access you can go for WebHook option. GitHub will notify your CI server when someone pushes the code or a tag.

Comment: no we were using TFS 2013, but we switched completely to git. So there wont be any TFS involved. We have already migrated our code from TFS to git

Comment: I understand, Are you going to use different build server?

Comment: Yes,  it will be a new build server

Comment: Ok, I see. Since I don't know what kind of build server you are going to use, I explained how to set up integration with TeamCity as an example.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Does it needs to be .sln file? We have several .sln file need to be build as a part of the whole build. We have MSBuild proj file created which builds all the required solutions and does few custom things. So far I am executing this .proj file using command line on our build server. I would like to execute proj file using CI.

Comment: The link to the step by step example has an extra slash at the end...thus the link fails.  I tried to edit the post, but this is a single character edit and SO requires 6 characters to save the edit. http://www.mehdi-khalili.com/continuous-integration-delivery-github-teamcity

Answer (score 0):

[AppVeyor](https://github.com/integrations/appveyor) is an increasingly popular CI on GitHub.

For example, see how [this project](https://github.com/JSkimming/AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.Multitenant) defines an [`appveyor.yml`](https://github.com/JSkimming/AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.Multitenant/blob/master/appveyor.yml) file to configure CI.

[image]